# Router cannot continously look for a Dynamic IP

Tags: router, home-networking, dhcp

I am trying to connect to a ISP provider who is running a DHCP service.

When I connect the cable provided by the ISP[beam telecom] to my laptop , a dynamic IP is assigned and everything fine.

When I am using TP Link Router WR740N(new) instead, dynamic IP is not assigned to the router.

I checked and compared logs from the router and laptop when connected to the cable , I observed the following difference

while my laptop running windows 7 even after a failed attempt persistently looks for an IP, while my router just quits the first time.

my question is how to configure the router to look for the IP continously, I checked the web interface for an option but I could not find one.

can I do a telnet to the router and change the configuration?

Comment: It's possible your isp is restricting dhcp addresses to the mac addresses of the routers it issues it might be worth looking for an option to change your new router's address to the one of your old router.

Comment: this is the first time I am using a router with this ISP, I tried to clone the mac address of my laptop to use with the router(using option in the web admin interface),but no luck.

Comment: Not the one of your laptop, the one of the router they gave you. That's what they are expecting to get the address request from.

Comment: I think you should be looking for the problem elsewhere. Why isn't your router getting an IP in the first place? Having it resend a DHCP request immediately will make it fail more often, but doesn't mean it will eventually succeed.

Comment: I guess the dhcp service from ISP might be taking some time to respond, this problem is handled by windows 7 by retrying while the router cannot.

Comment: Did you run the "Easy Setup Assistant" that comes with it?

Comment: yes, I did run it multiple times,restored the router to default settings,even then the dynamic IP is not acquired.While going through this process at one instance the IP was allocated.

Comment: -1: failure to disambiguate bad behavior of client machines (confused to be positive behaviors) from direct behaviors of the router.  Ambiguous declarations of router behavior.  Failure to clarify behaviors of specific pieces of network hardware (cable modem, router, switch/router, client systems)  (would nave been -2 or more if permitted)

Comment: @killermist I dont find your comment as a constructive one, this is the problem I am facing, I am sorry if it looks like a very specific case,I tried my best to describe the problem, I am not a networking professional, I assume that the router is based on linux, so if you could provide a pointer on tweaking the behavior of dhcp client on the router, that would be great.

Comment: I didn't mean my comment to be a "slam" against you.  I often will rephrase titles and bodies to make them more easily understood, but periodically, I'll come across questions where I come away with, "What?  I don't understand what this person is looking for."  And so, not only am I unable to paraphrase for them, but I feel the need to downvote because I'm sure others would have the same problem.  Then, the system encourages that I comment on why I downvoted so the  user isn't left wondering why.  So, I comment.  If you can clear up precisely what is and isn't happening, it'll help, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Many times the ISP's modem sees the Mac address as "sticky" so when changing devices you most power down the modem, power down the device (router, system, etc.). Power the modem back on, wait for it to complete its start-up then power on the device.
Also make sure that the router is properly connected and set to accept a DHCP address. Another check would be the cable - your laptop may do auto-xover and your router may not, so if your cable is of the wrong type the laptop will still work but the router will not.